# Select row number inside a select query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a `Select` query which returns data based on highest mark received as follows.

```
SELECT 
    Name, Mark, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Marks) AS Rank
FROM
    table_1
WHERE
    IsDelete ='false'
```

Result:

| Rank | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 10 |
| 2 | User2 | 8 |
| 3 | User11 | 6 |

I have another query which returns data from same table which have name matching to search text as follows.

```
SELECT 
FROM table_1 
WHERE name LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' 
ORDER BY Marks
```

| Name | Mark |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 10 |
| User2 | 8 |
| User11 | 6 |

I need the row number of each candidates based on their marks and matching the search text given in a single query.

The result should be like this when I enter 'r1' as search text

| Rank | Name | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 10 |
| 3 | User11 | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is with a CTE (common table expression), which often improves the readability (at least for me): e.g.

```
WITH HighestMarks (Name, Mark, Rank) 
  AS (
       SELECT Name, Mark, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Marks) AS Rank
        FROM table_1
        WHERE IsDelete ='false'
     )

SELECT * FROM HighestMarks WHERE name LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%' ORDER BY Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select Name, Mark, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Marks) as Rank
      from table_1
      where IsDelete = 'false'
     ) t
where name like '%' + @SearchText + '%';
```

Note:  You should not be munging the query with values such as `@SearchText`.  **Use parameters!!**